# Sending mail using flask + blueprint

Tags: flask, flask-mail

I have a question about the structure of blueprint

My flask structure looks like

```
app/
    main/
        __init__.py
        mail.py
    __init.py
manage.py
config.py
```

I register blueprint in __init__.py, for `app/__init__.py`

```
from flask_mail import Mail
from flask import Flask

mail = Mail()
def create_app(config_name='develop'):
    app = Flask(__name__)

    from config import cfg      # load EMAIL config from config.py
    app.config.from_object(cfg[config_name])
    cfg[config_name].init_app(app)

    from .main import main      # register blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(main)

    mail.init_app(app)          # load related mail config???

    return app
```

Put configs in `config.py`

```
class Config():
    MAIL_SERVER='<My e-mail SMTP>'
    MAIL_DEFAULT_SENDER=('TOPIC', 'mailID')
    MAIL_USERNAME='<EMail>'
    MAIL_PASSWORD='<EMail Password>'
```

It returns smtplib.SMTPSenderRefused error when I write codes like this in `app/main/mail.py`

```
@main.route('/mail')
def sendmail():
    receivers = ['<Receiver 1>', '<Receiver 2>'] 
    app = current_app._get_current_object() # <class 'flask.app.Flask>
    mail = Mail(app)
    with mail.connect() as conn:
        for receiver in receivers:
            msg = Message(
                        subject='subject test',
                        recipients=[receiver],
                        html='<h1>Hi~~</h1>')
            mail.send(msg)
    return 'ok'
```

It raise a 553 error

```
smtplib.SMTPSenderRefused: (553, b'Domain name required.', '=?utf-8?q?<TOPIC>?= <mailID>')
```

I did load config in `app/__init__.py`, but why I couldn't find MAIL_SERVER and related config in `app/main/mail.py`?

But if I reload config again in `app/main/mail.py`, it sends mail successfully

```
app.config.update(
    MAIL_SERVER='<SMTP>',
    MAIL_DEFAULT_SENDER=('<TOPIC>', 'mailID'),
    MAIL_USERNAME='<email>',
    MAIL_PASSWORD='<PASSWORD>'
)
```

I don't know why I have to do it twice

Answer (score 2):

You should use app_context() like this:

```
from flask import current_app
from flask_mail import Message, Mail

with current_app.app_context():
    mail = Mail()
    mail.send(msg)
```

more info https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/extensiondev/

Answer (score 2):

The following code is render HTML template for sending mail body including styles or formatted HTML.

```
from <project-module> import mail

token = user.get_reset_token()
msg = Message('Password Reset Request', sender='<sender-mail>', recipients=[user.email])
msg.html = render_template('email_templates/password_reset.html',
                               home_link=url_for('home.index', _external=True),
                               reset_link=url_for(
                                   'account.reset_token', token=token, _external=True),
                               name=user.name,
                               email=user.email)
mail.send(msg)
```

As you mentioned above code. I have been twice initialize Mail object, which is un-necessary.

```
@main.route('/mail')
def sendmail():
    receivers = ['<Receiver 1>', '<Receiver 2>'] 
    mail = Mail()
    with mail.connect() as conn:
        for receiver in receivers:
            msg = Message(
                        subject='subject test',
                        recipients=[receiver],
                        html='<h1>Hi~~</h1>')
            mail.send(msg)
    return 'ok'
```

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct answer to your question, but actually I don't think you need to initialize the mail twice.

If you would initialize the mail in `app/main/mail.py`, there's no point having `mail.init_app(app)` in `app/__init__.py` because you never imported it.

Otherwise, in `app/main/mail.py` I would do `import app.mail` without creating another mail so that you won't have this config issue in the first place.